# Assigning weights/percentages to care card activities in Apple CareKit

Tags: ios, carekit

Is there a way to assign relative weights to OCKCarePlanActivity instances, to differentiate their priorities (and enable adding optional activities)? For example, "jogging" and "taking chemo drug" would have very different priorities, but all activities account for the same percentage of completion in the Care Card.

I don't think this capability exists based on the CareKit docs, but just wanted to double check.